# Is it possible to build Wix/Wix# UI with MVVM?

Tags: forms, mvvm, installation, wix, wixsharp

I am currently reading into building a custom UI using Wix#, but since I have more experience with (WPF) MVVM than with WinForms i was wondering if it was possible to use that instead.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use WPF UI with Wix#. See example in [wix# repo](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/tree/master/Source/src/WixSharp.Samples/Wix%23%20Samples/Managed%20Setup/CustomUI.WPF).

If you want to use WinForms mandatory, you can also try to utilize WinForms bindings to write UI-related stuff in a WPF-style. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8.) about WinForms bindings. But in my opinion, WinForms bindings is not so good and I personally prefer not to use them in simple UI.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! but I cant run the example because WixSharp.UI.WPF doesn't exist in the nuget package. What do I need to do to access it? Greetings.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about WPF UI is ready to use. I was sure that I saw corresponding release notes, but really WPF UI support is only in development for now. You can try it by checking out master branch from Wix# repo, but I do not recommend to use it in production until release. Sorry again for my mistake.

Comment: i thought that would be the reason... thanks again!